# How to detect if GET request comes from an AJAX request or browser request?

Tags: javascript

I am writing an app using requireJS and the text.js extension. I now have a bunch of unstyled html templates that get their style once they are loaded into the parent template. Everything works fine. The only issue I have is that users can technically visit the url of the template and see an unstyled html page. Is there anyway to detect that these requests come from an AJAX request invoked by javascript vs a request that came directly from the user using a browser?

Comment: Add an var to the query string `?ajax=true` or test if `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` was not empty AND was from your domain. This can be spoofed of course. Another method is to block out the access to the folder of your templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway to detect that these requests come from an AJAX
>   request invoked by javascript vs a request that came directly from the
>   user using a browser?

It depends on how you are making the AJAX requests but most frameworks add some custom header. For example jQuery adds the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` request header on each AJAX request. This header can be used on the server to determine whether it was an AJAX request or not. And if the framework you are using to make an AJAX request doesn't add any custom headers you could add one manually yourself.

Comment: This is not browser specific correct? Should work everywhere as long as something like jQuery is included? Tested it out and worked perfectly for me.

Comment: No, this is not browser specific. It will work on all browsers. But as DarkBee pointed out it can be spoofed. But normally people that would bother spoofing that won't care about the CSS they get. So, as long as you are not relying on it for some security purposes you are perfectly fine depending on it.